# How to avoid memory leaks with the undocumented operator overloads for classes?

Tags: delphi, operator-overloading, undocumented-behavior

Delphi has a number of documented operator overloads:

For [records](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)) and [ARC_classes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)) (in the NexGen compiler).
Officially it does not support operator overloading for classes, interfaces or simple types.

Except...

[There are undocumented operator overloads](https://plus.google.com/+AgustinOrtu/posts/G7mJxL3S9EL) that **do** work on interfaces, [classes](http://www.clubdelphi.com/foros/showthread.php?t=91190) and [simple types](https://gist.github.com/lynatan/886ed984d230ac1b42dd89ed42ab2214).
(Although the undocumented operators do not seem to work on records).

E.g. The following code will compile and works:

**Operator overloading for classes in Win32/64**

```
//sorry for the horrible use of `or` to use for nil testing.
//I'd code this into a function (function FirstAssigned(a,b: TObject): TObject;
//It's just an example to demonstrate the concept. 
type
  TObjectHelper = class helper for TObject
  public
    class function &&op_LogicalOr<T: class>(A, B: T): T; static;
  end;

class function TObjectHelper.&&op_LogicalOr<T>(A, B: T): T;
begin
  if A <> nil then
    Result := A
  else
    Result := B;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  sl1, sl2, sl3: TStringList;
begin
  sl1 := nil;
  sl2 := TStringList.Create;
  sl3 := sl1 or sl2; // -> sl3 = sl2
end;
```

For reference, here is a list of all allowed operators:

**[List of operators](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tales/touch/searchdiary?word=*%5BDelphi%5D)**

```
class operator      class function          example
---------------------------------------------------
Implicit            &&op_Implicit           x:= y;
Explicit            &&op_Explicit           x:= integer(y);
Negative            &&op_UnaryNegation      x:= -y
Positive            &&op_UnaryPlus          x:= +y
Inc                 &&op_Increment          Inc(x);
Dec                 &&op_Decrement          Dec(y);
LogicalNot          &&op_LogicalNot         Not(y); //can be used for bitwise not as well
Trunc               &&op_Trunc              i:= trunc(f);
Round               &&op_Round              i:= round(f);
In                  &&op_In                 if (i in s) then
Equal               &&op_Equality           a = b
NotEqual            &&op_Inequality         a <> b
GreaterThan         &&op_GreaterThan        a > b
GreaterThanOrEqual  &&op_GreaterThanOrEqual a >= b 
LessThan            &&op_LessThan           a < b
LessThanOrEqual     &&op_LessThanOrEqual    a <= b
Add                 &&op_Addition           a + b
Subtract            &&op_Subtraction        a - b
Multiply            &&op_Multiply           a * b
Divide              &&op_Division           a / b //floating point div
IntDivide           &&op_IntDivide          a div b //integer div
Modulus             &&op_Modulus            a mod b
LeftShift           &&op_LeftShift          a shl b
RightShift          &&op_RightShift         a shr b
LogicalAnd          &&op_LogicalAnd         if (a and b) then ...
LogicalOr           &&op_LogicalOr          if (a or b) then ....
LogicalXor          &&op_ExclusiveOr        if (a xor b) then
BitwiseAnd          &&op_BitwiseAnd         x:= a and b
BitwiseOr           &&op_BitwiseOr          x:= a or b
BitwiseXor          &&op_BitwiseXOR         x:= a xor b
Include             &&op_Include            include(s, i);
Exclude             &&op_Exclude            exclude(s, i);
```

How do I avoid running into memory leaks when using these overloads with (non-arc) classes?

Comment: I know what you are getting at because I've seen the Google+ discussion that prompted this. But without any conrtext or justification, this question makes no sense. There's a good Q&A to be had here, but this isn't it. Please don't post half formed content. Take the time to flesh it out.

Comment: @Johan I don't think this question currently is a good fit for Stack Overflows Q&A style - can you narrow it down to an actual problem you face? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask (_You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page._)

Comment: A little. You avoid running into memory leaks by manually destroying any objects that are created by one of your operators. In practice that is going to be impractical. Obviously operators that return value types are going to be fine.

Comment: Did you ever think why it only is allowed "For records and ARC_classes", huh? What is the reason to implementing those extra checks instead of universally enabling? My bet is that reason exactly those memory leaks, that is very hard or maybe impossible to get rid of.
If Delphi compiler developers would find a way to implement it without memory leaks, they would do and that function would be ready out of the box. But if even CodeGear/Embarcadero/... did not find a practical way to do it - then it is truly a hard problem. Which means, no one has answer to it. Be first to invent it :-D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would say, it could be practical, providing Delphi would implement two features: Records constructors/destructors (or initializers/finalizers) - a looong time missed feature; and automatic boxing/unboxing of those classes/simple types into such records

Comment: @Arioch'The That would not help in the least

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why? We already have memory-proved operators over records. Now, box your values before the expression and unbox them later and you have it.

Comment: @Arioch'The what happens when you do A := B with those records. Now you have two references to the same object. Boxing is typically done the other way. Convert value type to reference type.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan with such an example you do not need boxing, you just assign the base type values. We talked about expressions. Like A := B+C; This way compiler creates hidden variable "expression result" of the boxed type, puts into it a new value calculated by the operator, like a new object ref for class types, then it unboxes it, putting the value (like obj ref) into plain-type A (and clearing the ref inside the doomed boxed-type invisible var, if it applies for the base plain type)

Comment: @Arioch'The and now you've got a double free

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, like I said, the unboxing operation should, if needed, clear internal reference. box is an alter-ego for the object, in the context of expressions, there is no point to have both boxed and unboxed handles to the same value. Unboxing creates the plain value and destroys the boxed value.

Comment: @Arioch'The Now you are being silly. You've just reinvented ARC. I've no interest in this discussion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan of course automatic memory management is either about GC or ARC, it is a huuuuge revelation you just made. And ARC is "invented" in Delphi since version 2 introduced long strings. But at least you did not say I invented boxing, that is assuring.

Comment: I think, the sample code does'n demonstrate the concept, since it does'n return a temporary heap object.